# Convert soap request xml payloads to a new xsd schema

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, wsdl

We have a soap webservices which saves every request payload as an xml file without soap envelopes as a backup. These xml files can be used to reimport or resend the same request. We often use them for tests.

With changing xsd schema the older xml files become incompatible. What would be the best way to convert them to the new schema?

My hope was that soapui could import xml files and convert a wsdl compatible  request but i could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to write an XSLT Transformation to do the conversion. You're not going to be able to automate it any further than that.